# Best approach for an internationalised payment gateway implementation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, payment-gateway, activemerchant

I'm looking to integrate a payment gateway into a Ruby on Rails applicaton. Although i have already implemented one before im struggling to see how i can implement one which will cater for different countries.

For example, if it was only a UK based app i could use a UK vendor (e.g CardStream), if it was only a US app i could use a US vendor (e.g. BrainTree), but i can't seem to find a vendor that caters for multiple countries.

I'm concerned that i am going to have to have both a UK gateway and a US gateway running alongside each other in the same application. Surely this is not the case and im missing something entirely?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are actually quite a few PSPs and/or acquirers who support both the US and Europe.  Most of these will have various flavours of API such as XML or SOAP.  Check out Chase Paymentech Europe dot com.

Best regards

Steve

Answer (score 2):

Elizabeth nailed it. A Payment Service Provider has to go through accreditation with every acquiring bank that they want to perform authorization/settlement with. In the UK for example the main ones would be Barclays, Streamline, FirstData, HSBC, Amex, Diners. There are costs and considerable time investments for each accreditation.

I've never developed for acquirers in the US, but I imagine there are a good number. Rinse and repeat for acquirers in other countries and you see it soon adds up.

PA-DSS and PCI-DSS requirements are 'global', so once certified there its not too bad.

You could just go with a UK provider and have your clients setup a receiving bank account in the UK?  All providers will perform multi-currency authorisation and settlement, so its a pretty standard setup.  We've developed for US clients using this system.

Comment: Having each user setup a UK based account isn't really an option here as the application in question is Software As A Service, so it would be a huge barrier to signing up to the application.

Answer (score -3):

My first answer was wrong, so I'm deleting it.  (I hit the delete button, apparently you vote to delete).

[Magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com/) is an ecommerce solution that supports multiple currency, internationalization, and different tax rates.  We've used it before for [Versatile Hangars](http://www.versatilehangers.com/).  The base locale for this site is US, but Magento supports multiple site on one install.  I haven't played around with a shared user list between to sites, but I'm sure it could be fudged.

Sorry for the quick answer before.  I hope this works for you.

Comment: Magento is PHP. And joshnesbitt says the application is rails.

Comment: Dude, there are no rails solutions. It doesn't matter the language it's written in. The user doesn't care, and with some simple apache config it'd be easy to do both. AND he said payment gateway *into* rails app not written *with* rails. Don't be so quick to downvote. Besides, if you look at my profile, you'd notice I don't care for PHP, so the fact that I'm even suggesting it...

Comment: Payment gateways have APIs which can be accessed via Rails no problem. Plus attempting to merge a Rails app with Magento would be very difficult.

Comment: Have to agree this is a completely backwards way to solve the problem